# My C code won't stop taking in inputs using scanf function

Tags: c

This is my first semester learning C and I have trouble with one of my homeworks.

It's a program to receive the lists of homework as sets of (t,d) and to evaluate the urgency of each homework. (t means time left until deadline and d mean difficulty.) The task is to sort the list primarily by the order of remaining time and if the remaining time is equal, to sort it by difficulty.

This code works perfectly well when the input is something like

> (1,0), (2, 1), (4,5) ...

But when the input is like

> (1,0), (1, 4), (2, 1)...

it won't stop receiving inputs. This happens when the 'time' of the homework is the same (or so I think). I can't figure out why it's doing this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1024

void insertionSort(int a[], int b[], int num);
void printArray(int a[], int b[], int num);

int main()
{
  int a[MAX] = {0};
  int b[MAX] = {0};
  int i, num;
  scanf("%d", &num);
  for(i=0; i<num; i++){
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    scanf("%d", &b[i]);
  }
  insertionSort(a, b, num);
  return 1;
}

void insertionSort(int a[], int b[], int num)
{
  int i, j, val, val2;
  for(i=1; i<num; i++)
  {
    val = a[i];
    val2 = b[i];
    j = i-1;
    while((j>=0) && (a[j]>=val))
    {
      if(a[j] == val){
        if(val2 < b[j]){
          a[j+1] = a[j];
          b[j+1] = b[j];
          j--;
        }
      }
      else{
        a[j+1] = a[j];
        b[j+1] = b[j];
        j--;
      }
      a[j+1] = val;
      b[j+1] = val2;
    }
  }
  printArray(a, b, num);
}

void printArray(int a[], int b[], int num)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<num; i++){
      printf("%d ", a[i]);
      printf("%d", b[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the **exact** input and output for which code dosent't work properly.

Comment: "or so I think". Don't guess. Test different inputs and use a debugger to find out exactly what the program is doing.

Comment: There is a case (route) where `j--;` is not executed at `while((j>=0) && (a[j]>=val))-loop`.

Comment: If you are not checking the return of `scanf`, e.g, `if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) == 1) {...}` you cannot have any confidence that your conversion succeeded and that you actually removed the value from your *input buffer*. If a *matching failure* occurs, the same value will be left in `stdin` causing all other similar calls to `scanf` to fail. Always **VALIDATE** ALL User Input.

Comment: If time remaining is same for two hws then which should come first the one with higher difficulty or lower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not continuously receiving inputs, instead it is stuck in an infinite loop inside the `insertionSort` function

You just need to add an `else` case and `break` the loop.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1024

void insertionSort(int a[], int b[], int num);
void printArray(int a[], int b[], int num);

int main()
{
  int a[MAX] = {0};
  int b[MAX] = {0};
  int i, num;
  scanf("%d", &num);
  for(i=0; i<num; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    scanf("%d", &b[i]);
  }

  insertionSort(a, b, num);
  return 1;
}

void insertionSort(int a[], int b[], int num)
{
  int i, j, val, val2;

  for(i=1; i<num; i++)
  {
    val = a[i];
    val2 = b[i];
    j = i-1;

    while((j>=0) && (a[j]>=val))
    {
      if(a[j] == val)
      {
        if(val2 < b[j])
        {
          a[j+1] = a[j];
          b[j+1] = b[j];
          j--;
        }
        else
        {
         break;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        a[j+1] = a[j];
        b[j+1] = b[j];
        j--;
      }

      a[j+1] = val;
      b[j+1] = val2;
    }
  }

  printArray(a, b, num);
}

void printArray(int a[], int b[], int num)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<num; i++)
  {
      printf("%d ", a[i]);
      printf("%d", b[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar: it is OK to remind users about answer acceptance, if you suspect they do not know how the system works. However, explicitly asking for votes is not very seemly, and it is best if voting is as organic as possible. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer Thanks, I just felt they did not know the upvote feature as well. Will try to be careful next time.